# Vuex filter state

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm at my first app in Vuejs Vuex.
I can not find the best way to filter a state.

store/index.js

```
 state: {
  projects: []
 },
 mutations: {
   SET_PROJECT_LIST: (state, { list }) => {
     state.projects = list
   }  
 },
 actions: {
   LOAD_PROJECT_LIST: function ({ commit }) {
    axios.get('projects').then((response) => {
      commit('SET_PROJECT_LIST', { list: response.data})
     }, (err) => {
     console.log(err)
   })
  }
 }
```

in the component:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    projects
  })
}
```

At this point I have a list of my projects. Good!

Now I added buttons to filter my projects like:
Active Project, Type Project ...

How do I manipulate my projects object (this.projects)?

With another one `this.$store.dispatch`

With another getters function

I manipulate the state without changing the status?

I'm a bit confused.

Some examples of filters on lists populated in Vuex?

**EDIT:**
I was trying that way:

```
this.$store.getters.activeProjects()
```

But how I update this.projects?

```
activeProjects(){
  this.projects = this.$store.getters.activeProjects() 
}
```

does not work

Comment: Did you read this https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend to keep your original state intact and filter its data by using "getters".

In fact, the official documentation includes an example of how to get all the "done" todos. It might be useful for you:

```
  const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: '...', done: true },
      { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    doneTodos: state => {
      return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
    }
  }
})
```

Getters reference: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
In fact I was trying that way: `this.$store.getters.activeProjects()` but how I update this.projects? `this.projects = this.$store.getters.activeProjects()` does not work

Comment: Ok, I think a bit of misunderstanding is happening here. If you need to modify your state you should use "mutators", if you want to get certain processed/filtered data without modifying state, you should use "getters".
 Try by removing parenthesis: `this.$store.getters.activeProjects` or `this.$store.getters["activeProjects"]`

Comment: I tried but I get this error back: `[Vue warn]: Computed property "projects" was assigned to but it has no setter.` I think the problem is up 'this.projects = ...'

Comment: It basically says that  "projects" is a computed property and you can't set any new values to it. Why don't you try creating a new property called "filtered_projects" in your data object and then you assign the result from "activeProjects" getter?

Comment: Yes I tried, but in the template I call the projects object. I try to call the project object with a getters...

Comment: Got it, please mark the answer as correct if it was helpful for you. Thank you!